# Will `std::future::then` allocate memory? Custom allocator possible?

Tags: c++, future, executor

`std::promise` has a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/promise) which allocates the memory used to store the shared state. In implementations of `.then`, which I have seen so far, one stores a function in a type erased manner similar to `std::function` *in* the shared state. The [Concurrency](https://github.com/stlab/libraries/blob/develop/stlab/concurrency/future.hpp) library of stlab even goes so far as to put a

```
using then_t = std::vector<std::pair<executor_t, task<void()>>>;
```

into the shared state (to enable splittable futures).

**Is there an intent to specify if an allocator could be specified for continuations?**

In [P0443R3](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0443r3.html) they say in 1.2.9 Properties for customizing memory allocation

> Executor implementations shall use the supplied allocator to allocate
>   any memory required to store the submitted function object.

I think this only means the storage for agents submitted via the `execute` functions not the pointer *in* `std::future`'s shared state.

I've looked into the recent proposals for futures or executors and I could not find anything. Recent papers seem to favour putting executors in the shared state of a future anyway. If an executor would have an associated custom allocator should this be used?

I feel like I miss something.

--

**Edit:** I thought about this more and I think I can grasp why one would like to leave this unspecified. If futures are ever parametrised by executors their shared state might schematically look like this

```
template <typename Executor, typename T>
struct shared_state_t {
    // some prevention from race condition, for example
    std::atomic<unsigned> flags;
    // some sort of exception or value representation, for example
    std::variant<std::exception_ptr, T> maybe_value;
    // some handle to continuation
    continuation_t<Executor, T> continuation;
};
```

where `continuation_t<Executor, T>` does not need to allocate memory. It could be a pointer to an internal execution agent of one executor `Executor` or something like `std::function<void(T&&)>` for another executor.